# Don't validate if @RequestParam required = false

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, annotations

I have created a custom validator annotation and I want to use it only when `username` is not null. I have an endpoint where `@RequestParam String username` is not required and everything is fine there. Problem is with annotation, because it validates `username` regardless of the existence of a variable. I want to validate `username` only If `username` exists. Here is code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get( @RequestParam(value = "username", required = false) @ExistAccountWithUsername(required = false) String username) {
    if (username != null) {
        return getUsersByUsername(username);
    }
    return getAllUsers();
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Filled
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ExistAccountWithUsernameValidator.class)
public @interface ExistAccountWithUsername {
  boolean required() default true;
  String message() default "There is no account with such username";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator:

```
public class ExistAccountWithUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ExistAccountWithUsername, String> {

  private UserService userService;
  private boolean required;

  public ExistAccountWithUsernameValidator(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
  }

  public void initialize(ExistAccountWithUsername constraint) {
    required = constraint.required();
  }

  public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (!required) {
        return true;
    }
    return username != null && userService.findByUsername(username).isPresent();
  }

}
```

EDIT: I have added parameter. `@Filled` is `@NotBlank` and `@NotNull`. Updated code. It return:

```
"errors": [
    "must not be blank",
    "must not be null"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom validator you can just perform a null check as below :

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)
{
    if(value == null)
        return true;
    return someFurtherCheck(value, context);
}
```

This way, it will be accepted if null, and checked if otherwise.
Also, if you want to reuse this validator elsewhere where null value should return false, you can either add an `@NotNull` on top of your field to be checked as well, or add parameter in your validator annotation that stipulates wether null value should be accepted or not.

The latest method can be done as following :

`@ExistAccountWithUsername` class :

```
public @interface ExistAccountWithUsername {


String message() default "your message";
Class[] groups() default {};

Class[] payload() default {};

boolean acceptNull() default true;

}
```

ValidatorClass :

```
public class ExistAccountWithUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ExistAccountWithUsername, String> {

private boolean acceptNull;

@Override
public void initialize(ExistAccountWithUsername constraintAnnotation){
    acceptNull = constraintAnnotation.acceptNull();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)
{
    if(value == null)
       return acceptNull;
    return someFurtherCheck(value, context);
}


 }
```

So now when you don't want to accept null values for this validator, just use `@ExistAccountWithUsername(acceptNull = false)` instead of just `@ExistAccountWithUsername`

Comment: @Nikolas I want to use this annotation in other cases too. I have added parameter with boolean required field, but my annotation have annotations like `@NotNull` and `@NotBlank` and they validate even If I `return true` in my custom validator

Comment: Then in this case, you can add a parameter to your @ExistsAccountWithUsername annotation to stipulate how it should handle null values, as explained in my answer. I will update it to provide a code example.

Comment: I updated the answer, it should fit your use case now

Comment: I have done like that. Look at my updated code and validation error. I have to totally off validation if `required = false` otherwise it checks other annotations that are "on" this annotation

Comment: And if `@RequestParam` is not required it doesn't mean that I should pass empty or null username because i will get a null pointer exception so I need to check`@NotNull` and `@NotBlank`

Comment: Yes, but doing this : ` if (!required) {
        return true;
    }` is then equivalent to having no validator if `required  = false` on your annotation which sounds quite strange...

Comment: Where as this one : `if(value == null)
       return acceptNull;` will return true only if the value is not required and no username has been provided which I think is essentially the behavior you're looking into

Comment: Oh, I am retarded. Your solution is good. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

I see you have probably created validating annotation `@ExistAccountWithUsername` already. Reuse it and add the condition to [`ConstraintValidator::isValid`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html) method.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (username == null) {
        return true;  // is valid
    } else {
        // ... further validation in case the username is not null
    }
}
```

In case I misunderstood your `@ExistAccountWithUsername` annotation. There is a very detailed guide at Baeldung's article [Method Constraints with Bean Validation 2.0](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints).